# Get used classes inside a dll

Tags: c#, assemblies, mono.cecil

I'm inspecting a dll file and I need to know which classes of other dll files are used in this dll file. With the first loop it's possible to iterate through all classes of the dll- but now I want to get a list of all classes, which are used in some way in this class (those classes have a specific naming convention "Some.Test.Class*").
Could the solution be to parse every instruction of every method of the class and than searching in the instruction for the name of the class?
Does anybody have a better idea?

```
foreach (TypeDefinition type in this.currentAssembly.MainModule.Types) 
{
    foreach (MethodDefinition method in type.Methods)
    {
       if (method.HasBody)
       {
           for (int cnt = 0; cnt < method.Body.Instructions.Count - 1; cnt++)
           {
               Instruction instruction = method.Body.Instructions[cnt];
               /*
                   ????????
               */
           }
       }
    }
}
```

P.S.: I must not load some referenced dll files

Comment: You will need to use reflection.

Comment: I'm a real newbie according to this. I got a hint from a colleague, that I have to use Mono.Cecil, because I need to parse the dll files without loading the referenced ones. Would your proposal with reflection be a problem?

Comment: Is this your own dll file? if it is, just delete the reference and look at the list of errors

Comment: @Sayse: yes, it's my own. This could work- but I would prefer a solution without doing modifications inside the dll...but if there's no other way, I'll do that

Comment: @bianconero yes it will load the dll.

Comment: @Dilshod: Ok, thx- than I can't use reflection...

Comment: @leppie: Now we know that the use of reflection won't be possible..

Comment: @bianconero: I did not say reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mono.Cecil:

```
private static List<MethodDefinition> GetAllInnerMethods(MethodDefinition method)
{
    var queueMethodDefinition = new Queue<MethodDefinition>();
    var hsMethodDefinition = new HashSet<MethodDefinition>();

    queueMethodDefinition.Enqueue(method);

    while (queueMethodDefinition.Count > 0)
    {
        MethodDefinition methodCurr = queueMethodDefinition.Dequeue();
        if (!hsMethodDefinition.Contains(methodCurr))
        {
            hsMethodDefinition.Add(methodCurr);

            IEnumerable<MethodDefinition> innerMethodsByCaller = GetInnerMethodsByCaller(methodCurr);

            foreach (var currInnerMethod in innerMethodsByCaller)
            {
                if (!hsMethodDefinition.Contains(currInnerMethod))
                {
                    queueMethodDefinition.Enqueue(currInnerMethod);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return hsMethodDefinition.ToList();
}

private static IEnumerable<MethodDefinition> GetInnerMethodsByCaller(MethodDefinition caller)
{
    return caller.Body.Instructions
        .Where(x => (x.OpCode == OpCodes.Call || x.OpCode == OpCodes.Calli || x.OpCode == OpCodes.Callvirt) && x.Operand is MethodDefinition)
        .Select(x => (MethodDefinition)x.Operand);
}
```